# Why my latest Google App version active on play store is not available for existing users on first update

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I asked this question to google support but think didn't get the direct answer. Hope my question is answered here

I have an App in Google Play store whenever I publish a new version of this App, my existing users getting the immediate version of the App instead of the most recent version which is published and available in play store for new users & whereas my existing user only gets the immediate version on the first update, for instance

**Problem**

```
>     let's say User A has installed App Version1 on date d1 which is available on that date
>     then let's say Developer has released App version2 on date d2 & Version3 on date d3 & so on
>     & lets now assume that the current new version is App version 10 on date d10 which is available on play store for all new users
>      the real issue is with existing users, say if our existing User A updates the App on date d10 we noticed the existing user is getting App Version2 which is next to their current version 
> instead App Version10 when updated first time, in which case the user has to update twice to sync with the latest version of the App
```

**Question**

Is there a way to deactivate old versions of the App so that users can only get the latest version, I can see in the release dashboard the old versions of the App as deactivate whenever the new version is active but that seems only for the records whereas the actual behavior is as explained above

Sorry for being so lengthy, thank you so much for your time